# multiple if conditions in lambda does not work as expected

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, lambda

I have a problem trying to piece together a multiple conditional if.

- `UDF.daysinmonth(x)` returns number of days in a month
- `latest_date.month` returns the month of datetime object (eg 3 for 2019-3-10) - `latest_date=df['offtake_date'].max()`

```
df.insert(loc=20, column='bbls_mbd_mth',value=df['bbls'] / df['offtake_date'].apply(lambda x: UDF.daysinmonth(x) if x.month!=latest_date.month and x.year!=latest_date.year else latest_date.day))
```

This doesn't work, `if x.month!=latest_date.month and x.year!=latest_date.year`. For all of 2019, it returns the latest day in the data rather than the number of days in past months. For 2018, it works fine.

This doesn't work either.

```
df.insert(loc=20, column='bbls_mbd_mth',value=np.nan)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ifor_val = df.at[i,'bbls']/latest_date.day
if ((df.at[i,'offtake_date'].month!=latest_date.month) and (df.at[i,'offtake_date'].year!=latest_date.year)):
    ifor_val = df.at[i,'bbls']/(UDF.daysinmonth(df.at[i,'offtake_date']))
df.at[i,'bbls_mbd_mth'] = ifor_val
```

But it works when I flip the logic

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ifor_val = df.at[i,'bbls']/(UDF.daysinmonth(df.at[i,'offtake_date'])
    if ((df.at[i,'offtake_date'].month==latest_date.month) and (df.at[i,'offtake_date'].year==latest_date.year)):
        ifor_val = df.at[i,'bbls']/latest_date.day)
    df.at[i,'bbls_mbd_mth'] = ifor_val
```

I think I am missing something real basic.... any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe you might have a trailing `)` in the line: `ifor_val = df.at[i,'bbls']/latest_date.day)` - also your if statements are grouped redundantly.

Comment: Hi Calvin. Glad that you solved the error on your own. When you can, you should mark your own answer as correct. In addition, I also urge you to present your code as `code`. That is much clearer. Many people immediately go looking for the code in a question, simply by the formatting. So always use code formatting where applicable. I made the edits for you this time. To get the hang of it, you can try formatting your code in the answer that you gave.

Comment: thanks. done. still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Julian for the prompt reply. I found out my error, it's a logic error. The missing bracket is just typo.

```
apply(lambda x: UDF.daysinmonth(x) if x.month!=latest_date.month and x.year!=latest_date.year else latest_date.day))
```

I wanted to apply the latest_day only if the date falls into the latest month and year. By doing the above, it's the same as

```
apply(lambda x: UDF.daysinmonth(x) if x.year!=latest_date.year else latest_date.day))
```

regardless of the month, which is not what I want. I reversed the logic and it worked

```
apply(lambda x: latest_date.day if x.month==latest_date.month and x.year==latest_date.year else UDF.daysinmonth(x)))
```